# how can I identify my SSL public key certificate?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, private-key, public-key

Amazon Cloudfront is giving me errors, either my private key doesn't match my public key certificate or my public key certificate cannot be parsed as it's invalid.

Using Godaddy for my SSL certificate middle man/provider, I got a:

.pem whoose contents beings with "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"

(I'm assuming that's my private key)

Inside Godaddy I am able to download some certs for the SSL, they are:

.crt (type = Security Certificate)
.p7b (type = PKCS #7 Certificate)

Is one of the above my public key? Or is there another way I am supposed to get my public key?

Comment: What errors? Post them. Edit the text into your question.

Comment: It doesn't tell me the error, it just says 'private key doesn't match public key' this is inside amazon aws, trying to configure cloudfront with https

Comment: So you got one of them wrong. Review your steps.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue before with bad CSR Request. 
According to GoDaddy:
To install a digital certificate, you must first generate and submit a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) to the Certification Authority (CA). The CSR contains your certificate-application information, including your public key. Use your Web server software to generate the CSR, which will also create your public/private key pair used for encrypting and decrypting secure transactions.

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5343/generating-a-certificate-signing-request

It also states: NOTE: When generating your CSR, **specify a key size of 2048 or higher**.

The key size is sometimes the culprit. Hope it helps.